FreeCAD: pattern of multiple depending features, best practice?
I'm designing a sheet metal part in FreeCAD.
the sheet metal part will be primarily some U-shaped thing. However it will have multiple (approximately 20) cut outs with displaced lugs like the first one in this picture:

However with my current approach FreeCAD is acting extremly sluggish.
What I did:

Make a sketch on the surface of the base consisting of a single rectangle
Make a pocket through the sheet
Make a pattern from the pocket
Select all cut surfaces in one direction of the pockets
Make a 60° bend on these surfaces with the sheet metal toolbox
Select all end faces of these bends
Add another -60° bend on these end faces

I bet there are a lot of different ways to achieve this and I hope there will be some with FreeCAD acting more quickly. I seem to have chosen the most CPU hoggish way.
